# Getting an "Error" for using a bare Except - Python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I get a sort of Error Messagge that I should not use a "bare Except ..."
I have to check the 'line of the text file' (saved in raw_results ...) in which the third charachter is a dot ('.').
Is there another way avoiding to use Try ... Except ?

Thx for help

```
with open(file_to_read, 'r') as fi:
    raw_results = fi.readlines()

date_of_game = []
home_team = []
away_team = []
home_team_goals = []
away_team_goals = []

for i in range(len(raw_results)):
    try:
        if raw_results[i][2] == '.':
            date_of_game.append(raw_results[i][:5])
            if raw_results[i + 1] != "A Tav.":
                home_team.append(raw_results[i + 1].strip('\n'))
                away_team.append(raw_results[i + 2].strip('\n'))
                home_team_goals.append(raw_results[i + 3].strip('\n'))
                away_team_goals.append(raw_results[i + 4].strip('\n'))
            else:
                home_team.append(raw_results[i + 2].strip('\n'))
                away_team.append(raw_results[i + 3].strip('\n'))
                home_team_goals.append(raw_results[i + 4].strip('\n'))
                away_team_goals.append(raw_results[i + 5].strip('\n'))
    except:
        ''' ... do nothing '''
```

Comment: if the except is doing nothing , why are you adding it , its purpose is debugging and catching exceptions , can you explain your reasoning for adding it ?

Comment: If I do not put the Except it does not work - I get a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: yes since you nee dto remove the try also

Comment: i needed why using the try/except in the first place for your example

Comment: Without putting a Try/Except I get :                                                                                
if raw_results[i][2] == '.':
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: so that's your real error ,

Comment: range(len(raw_results)-5)

Comment: you're asking for data that are not exisiting in your data , beyond your index range

Comment: No the error is because some lines of the file are not as long as 2 characters

Comment: okey , anyway to solve the bare exception error: you can add 'except Exception ar error : print'error) continue'

Answer (score 1):

to solve the bare exception error:
you can add

```
except Exception as error :
   print(error)
   continue
```

to continue it's looping

Comment: The looping works in every case, but now i get   "string index out of range"

Comment: i believe it's from raw_results[i + 5] for example if i = len(draw_results)-1 so you' re out of the range of the data

Comment: you can correct by limiting your range to range(len(raw_results)-6)